# How to update constraints if the table name was changed?

Tags: postgis

I modified the name of a Table in postGIS. But the constraints contains old table name. How can I change the constraints? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

try to alter your table for dropping constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

than add your constraint again after chanaging table name...

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME TO new_table_name;
ALTER TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT the_constraint_name;
```

i hope it helps you...