# Append table in PostGIS - Geometry Violation

Tags: postgis

In PostGIS I have imported a shapefile - some of this is Invalid according to PostGIS.

Following online help I have first split the invalid polygons into a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE s_invalid AS
SELECT * FROM sdata
WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(the_geom);

DELETE FROM sdata
WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(the_geom);
```

I then buffered the invalid polygons by 0 to sort out the issue:

```
UPDATE s_invalid
SET the_geom = ST_Buffer(the_geom,0);

SELECT count(*), ST_IsValid(the_geom)
FROM s_invalid
GROUP BY ST_IsValid;
```

All seems ok, now I want to append the cleaned-up polygons back into the original table and this is where I have an issue. I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO sdata
SELECT * FROM s_invalid;
```

But there seems to be a mismatch with the geometry type from the best I can see - I get the message:

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "sdata" violates check constraint "enforce_geotype_the_geom"

********** Error **********

ERROR: new row for relation "sdata" violates check constraint "enforce_geotype_the_geom"
SQL state: 23514
```

How can I sort this... where is the issue? Is there an easier way to sort this out?
Thanks, I really want to get to grips with this!

Comment: a) what geometry contraint do you have in sdata? b) what does select geometrytype(the_geom) from s_invalid; say?

Comment: OK, I tried: SELECT geometrytype(the_geom) from s_invalid
GROUP BY geometrytype(the_geom); and I get MULITPOLYGON and POLYGON - is this the problem...?

Comment: You may have POLYGON contraint on sdata.the_geom and therefore can't insert MULTIPOLYGONs. Check out, what is definition for enforce_geotype_the_geom.

Comment: Sorry how do I check that....

Comment: Do you have pgAdmin? Just look for your table in left pane ('Object browser'), and there's Constraints section. When you are using plain psql, try `\d table` - but I'm not sure, whether it describes also constraints.

Comment: Thank you found it: enforce_geotype_the_geom geometrytype(the_geom)='MULTIPOLYGON'::text OR the_geom IS NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have MULTIPOLYGON constraint in sdata table, but ST_Buffer creates some POLYGON objects. Try:

```
UPDATE s_invalid
SET the_geom = ST_Multi(ST_Buffer(the_geom,0));
```

(or, alternatively, change constraint, so it accepts also POLYGONS).

Comment: OK finally there - THANK YOU BOTH - I think I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

from my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33484/3071).

try to alter your table for dropping constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

than add your constraint again after chanaging table name...

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME TO new_table_name;
ALTER TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT the_constraint_name;
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I took the constraint off, then yes it would let me insert. The statement to add the constraint is throwing an error and when I tried to add it back through pgadmin it won't let me as it says one of the rows violates it.....